# How to normalize dataframe by standard deviation using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

Given the following dataframe and `left-x` column:

```
|       | left-x | left-y | right-x | right-y |
|-------|--------|--------|---------|---------|
| frame |        |        |         |         |
| 0     | 149    | 181    | 170     | 175     |
| 1     | 149    | 181    | 170     | 175     |
| 2     | 149    | 181    | 170     | 175     |
| 3     | 149    | 181    | 170     | 175     |
```

how may I normalize `left-x` by standard deviation using [scikit-learn library](http://scikit-learn.org)?

Comment: You can use Standard Scaler from sklearn.preprocessing module.

Comment: @ManishSaraswat, would you mind writing an example?

Comment: @JPVentura I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can normalize by standard deviation without using sci-kit-learn, as follows:

```
df['left-x'] = df['left-x'] / df['left-x'].std()
```

Or if you also want to mean-center the data:

```
df['left-x'] = (df['left-x'] - df['left-x'].mean())/df['left-x'].std()
```

Here `df` is your `asl.df[l]` variable.

The `.std()` method gives the standard deviation of a dataframe across the given axis. By selecting a column first, the standard deviation is calculated for that column alone.

If you need to do this a lot and want to avoid the clutter, you can wrap it into a function, e.g.

```
def std_norm(df, column):
    c = df[column]
    df[column] = (c - c.mean())/c.std()
```

You call it as:

```
std_norm(df, 'left-x')
```

Note that this updates the passed DataFrame in-place.

Comment: I am aware that I could do `(df['left-x'] - df['left-x'].mean())/df['left-x'].std()`, but it is a so common operation that I was wondering if there was `normalize` function out of the box.

Comment: @JPVentura if anywhere would expect it to be in pandas itself (rather than sci-kit) but not that I know of. You could just wrap this into a function to re-use to keep down the noise. I've added an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use scaling functions from `sklearn.preprocessing` module.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(df['left-x'])

df['left-x'] = sc.transform(df['left-x'])
```